# Overriding Magento Customer Grid to add a custom row class

Tags: magento

Issue: I'm trying to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

Code:

config.xml

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtmlext>
                <class>Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext_Block</class>
            </adminhtmlext>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <widget_grid>Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid</widget_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
</global>
```

Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php

```
class Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function getRowClass(Varien_Object $row)
    {die();
        return $row->getCustomerActivated() ? 'user-active' : 'user-inactive';        
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get this to work...please help

Comment: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` is always inherited, never directly used, so rewriting it has no effect. Do you actually need to add a custom row class for all the grids ?

Comment: This was in fact the issue. I needed to be extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid. Thanks for the heads up :)